# When I close cursor? RecyclerView with CursorAdapter Issue

Tags: android, cursor, android-recyclerview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I am binding cursor data in **RecyclerView**

I have done like:

```
        Cursor orderProductCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (orderProductCursor != null) {
            OrderDetailProductAdapter detailProductAdapter = new OrderDetailProductAdapter(context, orderProductCursor, tvTotalAmount);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(detailProductAdapter);
            LOGD("Order Product Cursor size  " + orderProductCursor.getCount());
            //orderProductCursor.close();
        }
```

If I remove comment of `orderProductCursor.close();` then **RecyclerView** displaying none of the records (Zero Records) but IF I COMMENT that line then its displaying perfectly.

So When I should close the cursor as its good habit to close?

Note: If I remove comment, Its calling Constructor of **`RecyclerView`** Adapter but not calling **`onBindViewHolder()`**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of passing whole `orderProductCursor` to adapter, take its value to `ArrayList` or `List`.

Comment: It will be time consuming process when large amount of data.

Comment: you are passing orderProductCursor as a constructor parameter. Are you using the same cursor to fetch the values inside your adapter ?

Comment: Yes, I have used [CustomRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59). @Gautam

Comment: try to use #finally block and close your cursor in finally rest of the things should be kept in try-catch block(set your adapter etc..)

Comment: I think its same as what I have done because *finally* block will execute every time.

Comment: close your cursor in constructor of adapter. `mCursor = cursor; cursor.close()`. You are just copying your `orderProductCursor` into `cursor`, and then `cursor` into `mcursor`. So i think closing cursor will also close `orderProductCursor`.

Comment: Currently I have done with closing cursor in `onDestroy()` of Fragment. I think its feasible way.